# Using string variables instead of string literals causes error

Tags: c++, string, debugging, easendmail

I am following this [guide](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vc.aspx) to send email in c++ . You can download the header files : `easendmailobj.tlh` and `easendmail object` at [here](http://www.emailarchitect.net/webapp/download/easendmail.exe)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "easendmailobj.tlh"
using namespace EASendMailObjLib;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //string email = "randomemail1@gmail.com";

    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    IMailPtr oSmtp = NULL;
    oSmtp.CreateInstance( "EASendMailObj.Mail");
    oSmtp->LicenseCode = _T("TryIt");

    // Set your gmail email address
    oSmtp->FromAddr = _T("randomemail1@gmail.com");

    // Add recipient email address
    oSmtp->AddRecipientEx( _T("randomemail2s@hotmail.com"), 0 );

    // Set email subject
    oSmtp->Subject = _T("simple email from Visual C++ with gmail account");

    // Set email body
    oSmtp->BodyText = _T("this is a test email sent from Visual C++ project with Gmail");

    // Gmail SMTP server address
    oSmtp->ServerAddr = _T("smtp.gmail.com");

    // If you want to use direct SSL 465 port, 
    // Please add this line, otherwise TLS will be used.
    // oSmtp->ServerPort = 465;

    // detect SSL/TLS automatically
    oSmtp->SSL_init();

    // Gmail user authentication should use your 
    // Gmail email address as the user name. 
    // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be "gmailid@gmail.com"
    oSmtp->UserName = _T("somerandomemail@gmail.com");
    oSmtp->Password = _T("somepassword");

    _tprintf(_T("Start to send email via gmail account ...\r\n" ));

    if( oSmtp->SendMail() == 0 )
    {
        _tprintf( _T("email was sent successfully!\r\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf( _T("failed to send email with the following error: %s\r\n"),
            (const TCHAR*)oSmtp->GetLastErrDescription());
    }

    if( oSmtp != NULL )
        oSmtp.Release();

    int x;
    cin>>x;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is there an error when i attempt to use string variables instead of  "   " ???

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "easendmailobj.tlh"
using namespace EASendMailObjLib;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string email = "randomemail1@gmail.com": //string variables

    ::CoInitialize( NULL );

    IMailPtr oSmtp = NULL;
    oSmtp.CreateInstance( "EASendMailObj.Mail");
    oSmtp->LicenseCode = _T("TryIt");

    // Set your gmail email address
    oSmtp->FromAddr = _T(email); // string variable instead of "   " , error is here

    // Add recipient email address
    oSmtp->AddRecipientEx( _T("randomemail2s@hotmail.com"), 0 );

    // Set email subject
    oSmtp->Subject = _T("simple email from Visual C++ with gmail account");

    // Set email body
    oSmtp->BodyText = _T("this is a test email sent from Visual C++ project with Gmail");

    // Gmail SMTP server address
    oSmtp->ServerAddr = _T("smtp.gmail.com");

    // If you want to use direct SSL 465 port, 
    // Please add this line, otherwise TLS will be used.
    // oSmtp->ServerPort = 465;

    // detect SSL/TLS automatically
    oSmtp->SSL_init();

    // Gmail user authentication should use your 
    // Gmail email address as the user name. 
    // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be "gmailid@gmail.com"
    oSmtp->UserName = _T("somerandomemail@gmail.com");
    oSmtp->Password = _T("somepassword");

    _tprintf(_T("Start to send email via gmail account ...\r\n" ));

    if( oSmtp->SendMail() == 0 )
    {
        _tprintf( _T("email was sent successfully!\r\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf( _T("failed to send email with the following error: %s\r\n"),
            (const TCHAR*)oSmtp->GetLastErrDescription());
    }

    if( oSmtp != NULL )
        oSmtp.Release();

    int x;
    cin>>x;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error

```
Error C2065: 'Lemail' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: when you write this type of question could you supply us with the "errors" ?

Comment: Do you need to use wstring instead of string?

Comment: `_T()` is for string literals, not for variables!

Comment: @Mike The answers there are either bad ones or ones that don't apply to this question, IMO. There is no need to perform conversions between narrow and wide strings, if you make sure to consistently use the same type throughout your code.

Comment: @hvd totally agree, removed link.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal and a `std::string` are two completely different things. Usually when a function `f` expects a `const char*` you can pass to it a string literal or you can use the method `c_str()` of a string like so `f(email.c_str())`.

However the problem here is that `_T` is not a function. It is a macro and it simply appends a `L` as prefix to string literals. There is no way you can use it for `std::string`. You will need to use some functions for the conversion.

Alternatively define a macro that does the same as `_T` and decides to use `wstring` or `string` depending on if `UNICODE` is defined. Try to read through the code and what does `_T` do and you should understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether `UNICODE` is defined.

If it is, use `std::wstring` instead of string. Also, remove the `_T` wrapping the string variable and add `.c_str()`

Comment: And for consistency, I'd say, do this by defining a `tstring` type (the definition of which depends on the `UNICODE` macro), and then use  `tstring` without additional conditional code.

Comment: @hvd On the contrary, I'd recommend getting rid of all the `_T`, `t`... stuff, and explicitly using either `char` or `wchar_t`.  The code you need will be different in either case anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's a valid approach, but there are also valid reasons for keeping code compatible to build in either the misnamed ANSI mode or Unicode. The code wouldn't be all that different for the two cases. `tstring email = _T("randomemail1@gmail.com"); ... oSmtp->FromAddr = email.c_str();` should work just fine, assuming `IMailPtr` supports both compilation modes too. (If it doesn't, then you're right, then just use whatever type of string is needed by `IMailPtr`.)

Comment: @hvd But as soon as you do anything non-trivial, you need different code for each of the modes.

Comment: @JamesKanze Fair point, but a surprising amount of code doesn't need to do anything non-trivial, and the bits of code that do can often be tightly contained in functions so simple that they are easily maintainable even if they need to have two separate implementations. But my experience probably doesn't match yours.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the standard Microsoft junk (more exactly, an
experiment that failed—what they wanted to achieve is
laudable, but what they actually ended up with is useless extra
complexity), you're best off getting rid of it: the function is
`main` (not `_tmain`), use `char` (or `wchar_t`, depending on
what you want, but it must be `char` in the declaration of
`main`) instead of `_TCHAR`, and forget about the `_T`.

As for the immediate problem, the `_T` is a macro that *will*
only work on string literals; that's the way it was designed.
If you use it on anything else, it may expand to something like
`Lemail`, which of course won't be known.

Comment: _'If this is the standard Microsoft junk'_ Yes, it's just another stupid, badly written windows macro :( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I hesitated with that expression.  To give Microsoft credit, they were trying to solve a difficult problem, or at least to make it easy for their users to solve it.  Regretfully, what they came up with doesn't work.  (I rather suspect, in fact, that there is no way to make this problem simple.  Handling international text is incredibly difficult, and all of the various proposed solutions in the past also have serious problems.)

Answer (score 0):

invalid usage of _T(); it is for string literals.

So that line should be;

oSmtp->FromAddr = email.c_str();

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of `_T`:

```
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#define _T(x) L ##x
#else
#define _T(x) x
#endif
```

So as you can see, it just appends `L` infront of anything passed inside it. So if you pass in a string, for example `_T("HELLO WORLD")` it would translate to `L"HELLO WORLD"` if `_UNICODE` is defined.

Similarly if you pass in any other token, `_T(email)` for example, it would convert it to `Lemail` which is why you are getting an error.

Work around would be to use `std::wstring` and `std::string` as:

```
#if defined(_UNICODE)
#define String std::wstring
#else
#define String std::string
#endif
```

and use `String email` instead.

Comment: Note that it doesn't just prefix it, it prefixes it as part of the same token.